# Android: Empty Image in ImageSwitcher

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, imageswitcher

I have an ImageSwitcher:

XML:

```
<ImageSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/is"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
        </ImageSwitcher>
```

Code:

```
is.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return iv;
        }
    });
```

And in my OnClick I switch between the pictures if there are some.
If I added pictures an click then, it always shows me one "empty/black" picture between some pictures.
I have an Animation:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.infromleft);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.outtoright);
```

But nothing more. You know if there is such an "empty/black" picture in an ImageSwitcher?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: The android:animateLayoutChanges="true" made the problem. Just delete it ;)